# stopping the next tag after a header tag from dropping to the next line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap panel and in the heading I have a h3 header tag. I want to right align a anchor tag next to the header title but the h3 tag drops the anchor tag to the next line.
If I make the h3 tag something other then a header tag then I loose all the properties of it. Is there a way to jsut remove the forcing of the header tag from dropping the next tag to be on the line below?

```
<div class="panel-heading yb-panel-heading yb-panel-heading-inner">
                <h3 class="yb-panel-title">Following <span id="followersTotalBottom" style="font-size: 16px; color: grey;">(@Model.TotalFollowers)</span></h3>
                <a style="float: right" href="/space/public/following">show all</a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All `<h#>` tags are block level elements, meaning they always exist on their own line. To force the functionality you want, set your CSS like this:

```
h3 {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put A tag inside H3

```
<h3>Following 
    <span>(@Model.TotalFollowers)</span>
    <a href="#">show all</a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the heading is a block element and thus uses the full width of its parent. You can make it `display: inline-block`, so its width fits to the content. You should not use `display: inline` since it will break your margins.

```css
.yb-panel-title {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel-heading yb-panel-heading yb-panel-heading-inner">
  <h3 class="yb-panel-title">Following <span id="followersTotalBottom" style="font-size: 16px; color: grey;">(@Model.TotalFollowers)</span></h3>
  <a style="float: right;" href="/space/public/following">show all</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? Please consider to always explain if you are downvoting.